# Why is "Complete My Developer stories" redirecting us to the questions section of Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

From the jobs section, we're getting the message that 'Your matches are on hold', and giving us a box asking users to 'complete my developer story'. And *whenever* we click "Complete My Developer Story", the website is redirecting us to the questions section. Why?

Where is the section of users' developer story? Why is the link itself not redirecting users to "User Developer Stories"?

Also, after completing the "Complete My Developer Story" using link `https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current?ac=1' from the source. The "Complete My Developer Story" box is not at all disappearing. This indicates few more bugs to me.

Comment: Even though it's styled as a button, the "Complete my Developer Story" is actually a link. Can you hover over it and post what URL it's linking to?  It's should be `/users/story/current`.

Comment: I said it is redirecting to `stackoverflow.com`, not at all going to `users/story/current`

Comment: When we hover url is `/users/story/current ` but it is actually redirecting to `stackoverflow.com` listing all the questions....

Answer (score 3):

We identified and fixed the problem with the "complete my developer story" link redirecting to the homepage instead of to the developer story page as intended. Thanks for reporting it, and we're sorry for any trouble this might have caused you.

About your second question regarding why the box asking to complete your developer story is showing up, I see that your story is completed now. Would you mind letting us know if you are still seeing it?

Answer (score 1):

For your original question of why the "Complete My Developer Story" button was sending you to the questions page, I'm not able to determine.  The link on that button (`/users/story/current`) can only redirect you to three places:

- Your existing developer story, if you have one
- The "create a developer story" page, if you don't have an existing dev story
- The site login page, if you are not currently logged in, with a redirection afterword back to `/users/story/current`

I'm unable to find a case where you would go to the main page. If you're able to reproduce the case and can provide any more details, that would be appreciated. Also, if you have any browser plugins that might be caching redirects or otherwise changing the behavior, try disabling those.

For the second question of why the "Complete My Developer Story" box is not disappearing: In order for a developer story to be considered "complete", it currently needs to have at least:

- A name associated with the user
- Technology tags you wish to work with
- A location where you want to work
- Some "experience" entries on the dev story, such as education, positions, posts, milestones, etc.

At this point, your dev story does not have any "experience" entries included, so it is not considered to be complete enough to include in all the matching routines.  Once you fill out one or more experience entries, that box should go away and you'll be able to get the benefit of our job matching logic

Comment: Unfortunately, it wasn't doing either of the three. Was signed in and not having an existing dev story still it was redirecting to `stackoverflow.com` and listing questions, instead of the opening page to create a developer story. That's a bug. After creating the story, if the story is in-complete the box must display that dev story is incomplete or percentage of the story completed if the story is 100% complete then dev story box must not be there. if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Added some data to dev story still that idiotic box complete your story exists and upon clicking on it again redirecting to `stackoverflow.com` listing questions. Please fix the bug.